# I am doing a toggle and I want to change the background color change of the div when the toggle function fired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

My function is:

```
function onClickChange() {
  let MyDiv = document.getElementById('myDIV')
  if (MyDiv.style.display === 'none') {
    MyDiv.style.display = ''
  } else {
    MyDiv.style.display = 'none'
  }
}
```

And my div is:

```
<div id="myDIV"> Hello world</div>

<div id="backgroundColor" onClick={onClickChange}>I am div with image and I need a background color change toggle functionality based on "myDIV" toggle functionality</div>
```

Just as an information, I am using css "styled-components".Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance!
Happy coding :D

Comment: where is your button?

Comment: Please edit your question, don't add code in comments.

Comment: In my case it is not a button it is the div with id "backgroundColor".

Answer (score 1):

For this situation, you can use easily react `state`.

Example:

render method:

```
<div className={this.state.myClass} onClick={onClickChange}>I am div..</div>
```

onClickChange:

```
 onClickChange() {
      const {myClass} = this.state // read state first
      if (myClass === 'red') {
        this.setState({myClass: 'black'}) // set some black class name
      } else {
        this.setState({myClass: 'red'}) // set some red class name
      }
    }
```

When the state is changed, your render method is automatically called.

Dont use `document.getElementById('myDIV')` in `REACT` its antipattern.

Comment: Ok thank you but what I need is show and hide "myDIV" and chage the background color of "backgroundColor" div at the same time. I mean under one function. Which is onClickChange.

Comment: @JahidJony In your render method, you can use if statement. Something like this: this.state.myClass === `red` ? <div id=myid>....</div> : null

Answer (score 0):

Check below code, to change background color you can use `style.backgroundColor` for clicked div

```js
function onClickChange(obj) {
  let MyDiv = document.getElementById('myDIV');
  //element.classList.toggle('mystyle');
  if (MyDiv.style.display === 'none') {
    MyDiv.style.display = ''
    obj.style.backgroundColor="red";
  } else {
    MyDiv.style.display = 'none'
    obj.style.backgroundColor="blue";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV"> Hello world</div>

<div id="backgroundColor" onClick="onClickChange(this)">I am div with image and I need a background color change toggle functionality based on "myDIV" toggle functionality</div>
```

Comment: It is showing: TypeError: Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined

Comment: are you passing reference as `this` in function call?

Comment: No, Should I have to use 'this'?

Comment: Yes to get reference of clicked div you have to use `this` otherwise directly get in function by `getElementById`